# Where do the logs directed to /dev/console go?

Tags: logs, console, devices, rsyslog

I'm studying RHEL 7.

If I add this line to rsyslog.conf:

```
kern.notice      /dev/console
```

Where will the messages with facility "kernel" and priority "notice" be logged?

If I run this command:

```
logger -p kern.notice "Testing Log Entry"
```

Where will I see the message "Testing Log Entry"?

Jordanm:

How do I define the terminal for /dev/console? Right now I have made no changes to the basic installation. So when I run the command:

```
echo "Testing" > /dev/console
```

Nothing happens. Not even any error. So where will I see the logs directed to /dev/console?

Comment: It goes to the console (`serial console` or TTY, based on your configuration).

Comment: Thank you. But where is this configuration done? Is there a configuration file where this is specified?

Answer (score 6):

The console can be any tty device, including a virtual tty like `/dev/tty1`, a real
tty like a serial port `/dev/ttyS0`, or a pseudo tty like `/dev/pts/8`.

The initial console is set at boot, and you can specify it with a boot option like `console=ttyS0,9600`, where 9600 is a baud rate. Usually on machines with graphics, it is the first virtual tty, which you can get to with `chvt` or ctrl-leftalt-1 or similar.

You can change the console by issuing `ioctl(fd, TIOCCONS, 0)`, where fd is a tty, and you have sufficient permissions (typically root). See man tty_ioctl.

To experiment, there is a `console on` command in the `screen` utility that will make your pty the console, though you have to be root for it to work and your host must support the ioctl TIOCCONS.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have syslogd running.
Make sure that your **/etc/rsyslog.conf** has the module for local logging enabled.

```
$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging
```

You could always output to a file instead of the Console.

```
ie:
kern.notice      /var/log/kern.log
```

You can use **tail -f /var/log/kern.log** to view the log file output in real time from any console.